# How to hide / change Z_Index of Tilemap if Player is colliding/ontop

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I'm new to Godot and am trying to develop a way for hiding a tilemap if the player is currently ontop of, or colliding with it. In practice, I'm basically just trying to have a Roof tile being displayed on houses, and when the player enters the building, the Roof tile will disappear.

This could be done by disabling the Visibility option under CanvasItem in the inspector, or changing the Z_index of that tiles Layer to something less than the ground, but I am struggling to figure out how to access those variables within GD Script since I'm pretty new to all this.

Any help with being able to access either of these variables and as example have the values change under a func _ready(): for debugging would be appreciated!

(If you know of a better way to do this, let me know aswell!)

This is Godot 4.0, thanks.

I've tried multiple ways of attempting to access these variables but I keep getting errors im not really sure how to solve since I'm new to this language and I can't seem to find any other related topics online.

```
extends TileMap

#@onready var animation_tree = $AnimationTree
@onready var tile_map = $TileMap.get("Layers/Roof")

func _ready():
    tile_map.set_layer_z_index(-5)
```

```
extends TileMap


@onready var tile_map = $TileMap.get("CanvasItem/Visibility")

func _ready():
    tile_map.set("Visible", false)
```

Both provides error: Cannot call method 'get' on null value

My Node looks like this, House node contains the walls/windows/ground tiles, and its child Roof contains just the roof tiles.
[image]

Comment: I tried it before and it didn't work, but I tried it outside of func _onready(): and it seemed to work there? Not sure why it doesn't work under _onready() unless its different from just loading into scene? Not sure what tells it to trigger. Thanks!